# laravel :select rows having max value

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have the following 2 tables ,

```
users                    keys

 id   name                id    key   customerid      date
 ___________             ____________________________________
  1    1name               1     1        1        2016-11-17
  2    2name               2     1        1        2016-11-19      
                           3     2        1        2016-11-18
                           4     1        1        2016-11-18
```

I want to get for every customer the ids of each key having the max date

```
Customers::with(['keys => function($query){
    $query->groupBy('key')
          ->select('id',DB::raw('max(date)'));
}])
->get();
```

Now I'm getting the max date and the id of the first row not the id of the record having the max date

Comment: @Strawberry this is the second time I open this question and everytime it's marked as duplicate knowing that it's not duplicate. I'm searching for an answer in laravel , the answer you provide is pure mysql which don't help me and it's not what I'm asking for.

Comment: What's wrong with DB::raw?

Comment: @strawberry in my query I'm using ' with' in this case not everything works with DB::raw,

Comment: I suggest you revise the question, identifying the parts of the problem which you do understand, and the parts which you don't - i.e. the way in which existing answers fail to address this particular problem.

Comment: This definitely isn't a duplicate, not the linked reference anyway. Surely those who would like to know how to do this eloquently would benefit - not everyone is comfortable mixing their 'fluent' code with raw queries. It's kinda bias -- nope, this is a duplicate because we've provided a way to do it in Python, meanwhile you're working with PHP.

@Nour Nehme, it's clear you're just going to be flagged as duplicate here, but if you try on another site, perhaps remove the `mysql` tag and keep it as `laravel` only and note in your question that you're not looking for a raw query solution.